# How to place a specific comment on top of list

Tags: comments

PLease help me with this requirement in D6.

I need to mark one comment as best, so this comment should stick on top of all comments posted irrespective of sort order.

How can this be achieved, any ideas?

Comment: similar conversation going on [here](http://drupal.org/node/1326648) give it a shot

Answer (score 2):

Found [Best Reply module](http://drupal.org/project/bestreply).

> Best reply module allows node authors to mark a particular comment as the best reply. It aims to encourage quality comments and to give some recognition to people posting quality responses.